# Convert unicode to the right word

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string like this one

> Servi\u00e7os e Inform\u00e1tica

How can i convert it to the right caracthers (Serviços e Informática) ?

Comment: Where did you get that string from? Please give more context.

Comment: So why aren't you using a JSON parser which will decode all this for you? There's no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your comment, this is JSON - so don't do the work yourself, use one of the existing JSON parsers. I like [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) myself, but there's also [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) if you want. There's no point in reinventing the wheel here, bit by bit.

Note that I mean you should apply an existing library to the *whole* JSON involved, not just the single string: you should never have to deal with a single string in this form, as the JSON parser should perform all the decoding for you.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use [`Regex.Unescape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx):

```
var noUnicodeEscapes = Regex.Unescape("Servi\u00e7os e Inform\u00e1tica");

// noUnicodeEscapes == "Serviços e Informática"
```

---

Update:

Since this is coming from JSON, you should be using the facilities of your JSON library to unescape the complete JSON response - that will take care of the Unicode escapes present in your string.

Comment: @Oded: Fortuantely we now have more context - it's JSON.

Comment: @JonSkeet - OK, but it looks like the OP is only giving an extract from the whole JSON result. If the _whole_ result needs to be parsed, I agree that this is not suitable, but if this is simply an extracted field, I believe he will be OK.

Comment: @Oded: If it's an extracted field, that suggests he's not using a JSON parser higher up to perform the extraction - which again begs the question of why not :)